# Node.js return variable used in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

In some modules I saw this strange way of initializing variable used in a callback.
This particular example is from `mssql` module:

```
var sql = require('mssql'); 
var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {

    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query('select 1 as number', function (err, recordset) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

What appears strange to me is that `connection` is used inside callback as if it is already initialized, and in fact it is.
However I would thought that `callback` should be run before function `sql.Connection()` does `return`. In fact there is no way to run anything after it `return`s.

So how does this thing work?

Answer (score 4):

The callback is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't run immediately. Because of this, it gets placed in a queue and run whenever the interpreter isn't doing anything. For example, try this:

```
var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    console.log('I run second');
});
console.log('I run first');
```

Comment: So they are betting on pure luck that the interpreter will be busy enough? You can try this in node's REPL to see that sometimes it's not: `> var c = (function(cb) { console.log('in func', c); cb(); return 1; })(function () { console.log('in cb', c); });`
`in func undefined`
`in cb undefined`
`undefined`
`> c`
`1`

Comment: @xaxa No, they know that it's going to go on the async stack because it likely has to make some kind of I/O call. See [this post](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop) for more details on how events are handled.